# How to debug the SAPScript forms printed in Update Tasks? (When break points in OPEN_FORM don't work)

Tags: forms, debugging, abap, sapscript

I am trying to debug a SAPScript form that I would print from transaction `MIRO`.

If I turn SAPScript debugging on, the debugger does not get called.

If I put a breakpoint in function module `OPEN_FORM` it is never reached.

I would like to debug my form, if possible.

The logic behind what is going on is a little complex. I see a lot of "BAdI" names being used in the code, but I do not have any experience with those, and would not know where to start with this problem.

The form that I am trying to print can be found in transaction `NACE`,

If more info is required, please ask, I do not really know what info would be helpful in this case.

**[EDIT]**

Steps to reproduce:

- I fill in the Invoice date and the other highlighted field. The highlighted number at the bottom is a Purchasing document, then I hit `Enter`
  [image]
- I fill in the Amount and Quantity for the first entry (the PD must have positions, but I guess you get what's going on here)
  [image]
- I Set the Correction ID to "Vendor error: reduce invoice" for the entry that i've already modified
  [image]
- I set the 'Invoice Amount Acc. to Vendor' and 'Invoice Qty Acc. to Vendor' fields to greater values than those in step 2 and hit `Enter`.
  [image]
- I check the 'Calculate tax' checkbox, and a negative value will appear in the 'Balance' field. Here it's `205,87-` EUR. I fill then the 'Amount' field with the positive value '205,87' so that the document 'Balance' comes to 0.
  [image]
- I hit `Save` in the global toolbar and then a popup appears asking me for to enter a bar code. I enter any numerical value there and hit enter. At this point I am greeted with a "windowsy" popup asking me to print the form.

Comment: Have you tried setting an external breakpoint in `OPEN_FORM`? In some other modules (like IS-H), the printing process is started using `CALL FUNCTION ... STARTING NEW TASK`, which made debugging awful until the new external breakpoints were built in...

Comment: Could you please put the exact steps you are trying to do, so I could reproduce them in the ERP instance I have the access to? Screenshots would be nice.

Comment: @vwegert yup. Doesn't work :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

When in the debugger, go to

**Settings > Change Debugger Profile / Settings**

In the dialog that appears, check the checkbox "Update debugging" (2nd from the top)

Now the breakpoint placed in `OPEN_FORM` will break.